# How to convert SQL query to HQL query with two tables and LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I have a problem when I'm trying to convert a SQL query to HQL.

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT RahHistoSaipAcogida.numicu, RahHistoSaipAcogida.fecharealiza, TaSaip.tipo_descri AS [Tipo Acogida], RahHistoSaipAcogida.paccomunica, RahHistoSaipAcogida.presentación, RahHistoSaipAcogida.infohlp, RahHistoSaipAcogida.infovolant, RahHistoSaipAcogida.infoddp, RahHistoSaipAcogida.observaciones, RahHistoSaipAcogida.nom_prof, RahHistoSaipAcogida.autoriza_informacion
FROM RahHistoSaipAcogida
LEFT JOIN TaSaip ON RahHistoSaipAcogida = TaSaip.tipo_codi
WHERE RahHistoSaipAcogida.fecharealiza BETWEEN :desde AND :hasta
```

**HQL Query**

```
session1.createQuery("FROM RahHistoSaipAcogida acog, TaSaip ts LEFT JOIN ts ON acog.tipo = ts.tipo_codi WHERE acog.fecharealiza BETWEEN :desde AND :hasta")
                .setParameter("desde", fechadesde)
                .setParameter("hasta", fechahasta);
```

**stacktrace**

> ERROR:  Path expected for join!  Path expected for join!

If anyone can help me, I would be very grateful. Thanks

Comment: Show your entiteis

Answer (score 1):

Your query must look like:

```
FROM RahHistoSaipAcogida acog LEFT JOIN acog.ts  WHERE acog.fecharealiza BETWEEN :desde AND :hasta
```

You working on objects and there properties not on tables

Comment: There is not need `LEFT JOIN` in this example.

Comment: @v.ladynev Why you think so?

Comment: It is not used.

Comment: @v.ladynev And why do you think so? it is used in the Output!

Comment: What will we have as an output?

Comment: @v.ladynev an object Array containing all properties of both tables

Comment: Okay. If you think so, let's it be so :)